# IntelliJ IDEA resetting cursor position every half second

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ 2017.1 is driving me crazy when it resets the cursor position while I am typing. I thought it was saving every while but I changed the 'Save files automatically if application is idle' to 300 sec and unchecked 'Save files on frame deactivation' under Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings and the problem persisted.

Note that I have Jalopy Formatter and Save Actions plugins enabled but I don't know if they are the ones responsible for this fugly behavior and I can't seem to find options to increase the delay in which it re-parses the code and resets the cursor.

The reason that I am annoyed is because sometimes I have to pause and think before continuing writing code but the cursor resets and now I'm messing things up.

**UPDATE**: I tried to disable both plugins but the issue persisted.

```
class FooClass {
     void foo() {
           //the cursor is blinking at this position
     }
}
```

Then it resets to

```
class FooClass {
    void foo() {
//after one second, it goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: So disable those plugins.

Comment: @Meo I can't disable Jalopy because it's important for formatting the code according to certain company rules but I disabled Save Actions and the problem is still there

Comment: Does disabling Jalopy plug-in help? If so, just file a bug to plug-in developers so that they can fix it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I just tried it and no the the cursor is resetting still within around 1 second

Comment: Do you have any other plug-ins enabled when it happens?

Comment: @CrazyCoder SonarLint but it does analysis and in theory, shouldn't be interfering with such a behavior

Comment: Remove/rename [IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) to start with the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to disable SonarLint plugin to check if it was causing this ugly behavior even though it has nothing to do with formatting and saving. Seems like it was indeed.

SonarQube is a tool that does static analysis for the code. SonarLint is a plugin for IntelliJ and Eclipse that checks with the SonarServer to see if the user code is compliant with the rules of quality.

It seems like SonarLint kind of invokes the save on the file before running the analysis to notify the user of any possible issues. And it does this every second when the user is not typing.

Also, there isn't any configuration from the plugin to disable this fugly behavior. I will report this bug to them.

Comment: Could you please share the link to the issue you created? Was there any progress in that regard yet?

Comment: @geld0r I did not report the bug. Could you please do it?